# CouchBase .NET sdk use data upsert and spring framwork findone null

Tags: .net, spring, couchbase

Couchbase SDK .NET(Ver:2.2.2) and SpringFramework(Ver:1.4.2.RELEASE) used

Test Case

1. .NET Upsert -> .NET GetDocument : Success
2. Spring Save -> Spring FindOne : Success
3. Spring Save -> .NET GetDocument : Success

**4. .NET Upsert -> Spring FindOne : Fail**

Why shouldn't I do not know ... Help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW0a6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ubjW.png)

.NET Code

```
    var config = new ClientConfiguration
    {
        Servers = new List<Uri>
        {
            new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools")
        },

        Serializer = () => new JilSerializer()
    };

    using (var cluster = new Cluster(config))
    {
        IBucket bucket = null;
        try
        {
            bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("Test", "Test");

            cItemInfo TempClass = new cItemInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                TestClass temp = new TestClass();
                temp.var1 = i;
                temp.var2 = i;
                temp.var3 = ".NET Testing";
                TempClass.test.Add(temp);
            }
            TempClass.result = 200;

            string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TempClass);

            var document = new Document<cItemInfo>();
            document.Id = "TestClass_NET";
            document.Content = TempClass;

            var upsert = bucket.Upsert(document);
            if (upsert.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("Success");

            Console.Read();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bucket != null)
            {
                cluster.CloseBucket(bucket);
            }
        }
    }
```

Spring Framework Code

```
// [WS_ItemInfo.java]
@RequestMapping("GetItemInfoEx")
public @ResponseBody C_ItemInfo  GetItemInfoEx() {

    C_ItemInfo item = itemInfo.getItemInfo("TestClass_NET");

    return item;
}

// [CS_ItemInfo.java]
@Component
public class CS_ItemInfo {

@Autowired
private CR_ItemInfo itemInfo;

public void setItemInfo(C_ItemInfo item) {
    itemInfo.save(item);
}

public C_ItemInfo getItemInfo(String uID) {
    return itemInfo.findOne(uID);
}

public boolean getItemInfoExists(String uID) {
    return itemInfo.exists(uID);
}
}

// [CR_ItemInfo.java]
public interface CR_ItemInfo extends CrudRepository<C_ItemInfo, String> {

}

// [CouchbaseConfig.java]
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
@Configuration
public class CouchBaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected List<String> bootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter() throws Exception {
        MappingCouchbaseConverter converter = new MyMappingCouchbaseConverter(couchbaseMappingContext());
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        return converter;
    }

    private class MyMappingCouchbaseConverter extends MappingCouchbaseConverter {
        public MyMappingCouchbaseConverter(
                MappingContext<? extends CouchbasePersistentEntity<?>, CouchbasePersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
            super(mappingContext);

            typeMapper = new DefaultCouchbaseTypeMapper(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of the .NET SDK and Spring Data are you using?

Comment: Couchbase Ver .NET : 2.2.2 Springframework : 1.4.2.RELEASE

Comment: Is there any error or status message on the Spring side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Couchbase 1.4.2 is based on the "older" generation of SDKs (Java SDK 1.4.2 as well). Cross-compatibility between SDKs was not supported with this generation and was a focus of the second generation of SDKs (to which the .NET 2.2.2 belongs, but not the Java 1.4.2 one).

Second-generation Spring Data Couchbase 2.0.x is currently [in Release Candidate](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/december/spring-data-couchbase-2.0-release-candidate-quickannounce) and should produce documents that are cross-compatible with .NET 2.2.2.